# Send member reminder based on their last login SQL statement

Tags: mysql

Member Table Columns [id, email, join_date]

Member Login Table Columns [m_id, date]

Every time a user logs in, a new row is created in the Member Login Table.

I am trying to send them an email reminder when they have not logged in for 30 days. I stuck trying to get the list of users [email addresses], from the tables listed, based on the last time they logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT members.email, MAX(member_login.date_login)
FROM   members
INNER JOIN member_login
ON members.id = member_login.m_id
group by members.email
having MAX(member_login.date_login) < CURDATE - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
```

Comment: This lists the same user multiple times. The problem I am running into is grouping the users in the members_login table and then ordering them so that it lists them by the last login.

Comment: Whoops, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that it contained all logins, not just the most recent. The modified version should work.

Comment: Thank you much, Jeremy. That's just what I needed. Have a great rest of the night.